# Need to download a google finance spread sheet daily using python

Tags: python, csv

From "finance.google.com/finance/portfolio" I need to download daily the spread sheet which has details of price of the stocks.

Link:
https://finance.google.com/finance/portfolio

I had tried below code, but the .csv file downloaded is not showing any stocks details.Also please help me in auto downloading the spread sheet from Mon-Friday at around 3.30pm.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib

testfile = urllib.URLopener()
testfile.retrieve("https://finance.google.com/finance/portfolio?action=viewt&pid=1&ei=xxxxxxxabc=csv", "file.csv")
```

Comment: You need to sign in.

Comment: @BartoszKP: yes, I have a google account and have created a portfolio, and want to download that .csv file daily.

Comment: No, you have not signed in.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [`googlefinance`](https://github.com/hongtaocai/googlefinance) library

install with pip

```
$pip install googlefinance
```